# Ruby Rails: How to generate QR code images in different color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

I am using `rqrcode_png` gem to generate QR codes images in png format https://github.com/DCarper/rqrcode_png.

QR codes are generated successfully in png image format but the color of QR code is black & white and I want to generate QR code in blue & white format.

I search a lot on the internet but not found any answer on this. Also the documentation of `rqrcode_png` gem doesn't specify any way to change the color of QR code.

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rqrcode_png` uses `chunky_png` to generate images. The colors are defined in `rqrcode_png/lib/rqrcode_png/image.rb`

```
module RQRCodePNG
 class Image
   BLACK = ::ChunkyPNG::Color::BLACK
   WHITE = ::ChunkyPNG::Color::WHITE    
   TRANSPARENT = ::ChunkyPNG::Color::TRANSPARENT
   ...
```

I would try to overwrite that method and set blue as a constant

```
BLUE = ::ChunkyPNG::Color.rgb(0,0,205)
```

or, you can use the predefined colors in `chunky_png`

```
BLUE = ::ChunkyPNG::Color::PREDEFINED_COLORS[:blue]
```

Have not tested it but it's a theory. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Thomas is there any way we can insert any logo inside qrcode by using ror app?