# Generate QR codes with a logo or having background colors in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

I'm using [rQrCode](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode) for generating QR Codes in Ruby. But I want to change the background colors or add an image in the middle of that generated QR Codes. I did some research but found nothing.

Have anyone implemented it in Ruby yet? Or do you have any idea about it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check whether this can be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531726/ruby-rails-how-to-generate-qr-code-images-in-different-color

Answer (score 8):

> I'm using [rQrCode](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode) for generating QR Codes in Ruby. But I want to change the background colors [...]

Reviewing the [rQrCode documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rqrcode) you change the fill colour of QR codes using the following `:color` options when creating the QR code as either an image, ANSI, SVG or HTML table, as follows:

```
require "rqrcode"

qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691235/generate-qr-codes-with-a-logo-or-having-background-colors-in-ruby")
image = qrcode.as_png(color: "000")
svg = qrcode.as_svg(color: "000")
html = qrcode.as_html # `td.black { border-color: #000; }` in stylesheet
string = qrcode.as_ansi(dark: "\033[40m")
```

You can also change the background colour, use the `fill` option instead

```
qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691235/generate-qr-codes-with-a-logo-or-having-background-colors-in-ruby")
image = qrcode.as_png(fill: "000")
svg = qrcode.as_svg(fill: "000")
html = qrcode.as_html # `table { background-color: #000; }` in stylesheet
string = qrcode.as_ansi(light: "\033[40m")
```

These can either be used together or alone, its up to you.

However, I will warn you that depending on the contrast of the colours used, it may not be able readable by your, or someone else's, QR scanner. Also, change the QR code black squares to a different colour can break the QR code or not be register by the scanner.

As for appending or merging an image

> [...] or add an image in the middle of that generated QR Codes.

Generate your QR code as before and give it a [Transparent background colour](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chunky_png/1.2.0/ChunkyPNG/Color)

```
# require "chunky_png" # this already required by `rqrcode`
require "rqrcode"

qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691235/generate-qr-codes-with-a-logo-or-having-background-colors-in-ruby")

TRANSPARENT = ::ChunkyPNG::Color::TRANSPARENT
qr_image = qrcode.as_png(fill: TRANSPARENT, module_px_size: 4)
```

_ You can ignore the `module_px_size: 4` option, it was useful in my following example._

Then load your logo as a separate image and compose a new image with a reasonable width & height offset; I center the known smaller image within the larger image

```
logo = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file("logo.png")

height = (logo.dimension.height / 2).floor - (qr_image.dimension.height / 2).floor
width  = (logo.dimension.width  / 2).floor - (qr_image.dimension.width  / 2).floor

qr_composed = logo.compose(qr_image, width, height)
qr_composed.save("qr_composed.png")
```

[image: a QR code image (with a transparent background) overlaid a logo image]

*I have omitted logic to determine which is the large image before composing them, otherwise you will likely in encounter an out of bounds error, like so*

```
~/gems/2.3.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/operations.rb:393:in `check_size_constraints!': Background image width is too small! (ChunkyPNG::OutOfBounds)
```

However, you can create a new blank image and merge the logo & QR code images either horizontally; e.g.

```
new_width  = logo.dimension.width + qr_image.dimension.width
qr_merged_horizontally = ChunkyPNG::Image.new(new_width, logo.dimension.height, ::ChunkyPNG::Color::WHITE)
qr_merged_horizontally.compose!(logo, 0, 0)
qr_merged_horizontally.compose!(qr_image, logo.dimension.width)
qr_merged_horizontally.save("qr_merged_horizontally.png")
```

[image: logo and QR code position beside one another]

Or vertically; e.g.

```
new_height = logo.dimension.height + qr_image.dimension.height
qr_merged_vertically   = ChunkyPNG::Image.new(logo.dimension.width, new_height, ::ChunkyPNG::Color::WHITE)
qr_merged_vertically.compose!(logo, 0, 0)
qr_merged_vertically.compose!(qr_image, 0, logo.dimension.height)
qr_merged_vertically.save("qr_merged_vertically.png")
```

[image: logo and QR code images stack vertically]

By combining their widths or heights respectively.

*Otherwise, it will require more external information or manual manipulation to position the images amongst one another.*

**References:**

- [File: README — Documentation for rqrcode (0.10.1)](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rqrcode)
- [Module: ChunkyPNG::Color — Documentation for chunky_png (1.2.0)](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chunky_png/1.2.0/ChunkyPNG/Color)

Answer (score 2):

You can overlay any image in the middle as long as it covers less area than the QR code error correction level. It's pretty simple to do with the current version of RQRCode (2.0.0):

```rb
qr_code = RQRCode::QRCode.new("some data", level: :h)

qr_code_png = qr_code.as_png(size: 600)
logo = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file('some/path/logo.png')

qr_code_png.compose!(logo, 200, 200) # adjust the coordinates according to the logo size
qr_code_png.to_blob # binary file result
```